# MVC C# disabled bool gets saved as false

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC where some of the bools are Checked (set to true) and disabled. When I POST the form, they always gets passed in as False. How do I determine what the original value of the bool, in this case TRUE?

Answer (score 2):

> When I POST the form, they always gets passed in as False.

Actually, they aren't being sent *at all*.  You can see this if you look at the JSON sent on the wire using a tool like Fiddler.

Disabled field controls are omitted from form data.  Make it `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled):

> Indicates whether the element is disabled or not. If this attribute is set to true the element is disabled. Disabled elements are usually drawn with grayed-out text. If the element is disabled, it does not respond to user actions, it cannot be focused, and the command event will not fire. **In the case of form elements, it will not be submitted**

Compare this to [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/readonly):

> If set to true, then the user cannot change the value of the element. However, the value may still be modified by a script.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'readonly' checkbox (setting `readonly` has no affect at all and the user can toggle the state by clicking on it)

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when programming in ASP3.
You may have to re-enable the checkbox right before posting the page.

Or you can change it to readonly as Amy said.